How to merge videos without overlap maintaining ratio 16:9 using ffmpeg
I have 2 videos in format 16:9. I need to merge together without any overlap and I need to keep final ratio 16:9 as well. One video need to be large (covering 80 % or more) and other has to be smaller in the right bottom corner.
How can I achieve this using ffmpeg?
Final result desired

Found the solution, hopefully it will help somebody:
 -i 39007973_slides.mp4
 -i 39007973_video.mp4
 -filter_complex "
  color=s=1920x1080:c=black [base];
  [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1600x900 [upperleft];
  [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x180 [bottomright];
  [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
  [tmp1][bottomright] overlay=shortest=1:x=1600:y=900
 "
 -c:v libx264 output.mkv


Hello, first of all, question should normally start with command(s) you tried. Secondly, answers should go into answers with a bit of explantation of why they are optimal here.
